# Why are mongodb queries to a localhost instance of mongo so much faster than to a cloud instance?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, latency

I'm using [this code](https://github.com/dwjohnston/mongo-performance-expirements) to run the tests outlined in [this blog post](https://medium.com/faun/performance-tips-for-mongodb-mongoose-190732a5d382).

(For posterity, relevant code pasted at the bottom).

What I've found is that if I run these experiments with a local instance of Mongo (in my case, using docker)

```
docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -v ~/data:/data/db mongo
```

Then I get pretty good performance, similar results as outlined in the blog post:

```
finished populating the database with 10000 users
default_query: 277.986ms
query_with_index: 262.886ms
query_with_select: 157.327ms
query_with_select_index: 136.965ms
lean_query: 58.678ms
lean_with_index: 65.777ms
lean_with_select: 23.039ms
lean_select_index: 21.902ms
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting
```

However, when I switch do using a cloud instance of Mongo, in my case an Atlas sandbox instance, with the following configuration:

```
CLUSTER TIER
M0 Sandbox (General)
REGION
GCP / Iowa (us-central1)
TYPE
Replica Set - 3 nodes
LINKED STITCH APP
None Linked
```

(Note that I'm based in Melbourne, Australia).

Then I get *much* worse performance.

```
adding 10000 users to the database
finished populating the database with 10000 users
default_query: 8279.730ms
query_with_index: 8791.286ms
query_with_select: 5234.338ms
query_with_select_index: 4933.209ms
lean_query: 13489.728ms
lean_with_index: 10854.134ms
lean_with_select: 4906.428ms
lean_select_index: 4710.345ms
```

I get that obviously there's going to be some round trip overhead between my computer and the mongo instance, but I would expect that to add 200ms max.

It seems that that round trip time must be being added multiple times, or something completely else that I'm not aware of - can someone explain just what it is that would cause this to blow out?

A good answer might involve doing an explain plan, and explaining that in terms of network latency.

**Tests against different Atlas instances**  - For those suggesting the issue is that I'm using a Sandbox instance of Atlas - here is the results for a M20 and M30 instances:

```
BACKUPS
Active
CLUSTER TIER
M20 (General)
REGION
GCP / Iowa (us-central1)
TYPE
Replica Set - 3 nodes
LINKED STITCH APP
None Linked
BI CONNECTOR
Disabled
```

```
adding 10000 users to the database
finished populating the database with 10000 users
default_query: 9015.309ms
query_with_index: 8779.388ms
query_with_select: 4568.794ms
query_with_select_index: 4696.811ms
lean_query: 7694.718ms
lean_with_index: 7886.828ms
lean_with_select: 3654.518ms
lean_select_index: 5014.867ms
```

```
BACKUPS
Active
CLUSTER TIER
M30 (General)
REGION
GCP / Iowa (us-central1)
TYPE
Replica Set - 3 nodes
LINKED STITCH APP
None Linked
BI CONNECTOR
Disabled
```

```
adding 10000 users to the database
finished populating the database with 10000 users
default_query: 8268.799ms
query_with_index: 8933.502ms
query_with_select: 4740.234ms
query_with_select_index: 5457.168ms
lean_query: 9296.202ms
lean_with_index: 9111.568ms
lean_with_select: 4385.125ms
lean_select_index: 4812.982ms
```

These really don't show any significant difference (be aware than any difference may just be network noise).

**Tests colocating the Mongo client and the mongo database instance**

I created a docker container and ran it on Google's Cloud Run, in the same region (US Central1), the results are:

```
2019-12-30 11:46:06.814 AEDTfinished populating the database with 10000 users
2019-12-30 11:46:07.885 AEDTdefault_query: 1071.233ms
2019-12-30 11:46:08.917 AEDTquery_with_index: 1031.952ms
2019-12-30 11:46:09.375 AEDTquery_with_select: 457.659ms
2019-12-30 11:46:09.657 AEDTquery_with_select_index: 281.678ms
2019-12-30 11:46:10.281 AEDTlean_query: 623.417ms
2019-12-30 11:46:10.961 AEDTlean_with_index: 680.622ms
2019-12-30 11:46:11.056 AEDTlean_with_select: 94.722ms
2019-12-30 11:46:11.148 AEDTlean_select_index: 91.984ms
```

So while this doesn't give results as fast as running on my own machine - it does show that colocating the client and the database gives a very large performance improvement.

So the question again is - why is the improvement ~7000ms?

**The test code:**

```
(async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/perftest', {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useCreateIndex: true
    })

    await init()

    // const query = { age: { $gt: 22 } }
    const query = { favoriteFruit: 'potato' }

    console.time('default_query')
    await User.find(query)
    console.timeEnd('default_query')

    console.time('query_with_index')
    await UserWithIndex.find(query)
    console.timeEnd('query_with_index')

    console.time('query_with_select')
    await User.find(query)
      .select({ name: 1, _id: 1, age: 1, email: 1 })
    console.timeEnd('query_with_select')

    console.time('query_with_select_index')
    await UserWithIndex.find(query)
      .select({ name: 1, _id: 1, age: 1, email: 1 })
    console.timeEnd('query_with_select_index')

    console.time('lean_query')
    await User.find(query).lean()
    console.timeEnd('lean_query')

    console.time('lean_with_index')
    await UserWithIndex.find(query).lean()
    console.timeEnd('lean_with_index')

    console.time('lean_with_select')
    await User.find(query)
      .select({ name: 1, _id: 1, age: 1, email: 1 })
      .lean()
    console.timeEnd('lean_with_select')

    console.time('lean_select_index')
    await UserWithIndex.find(query)
      .select({ name: 1, _id: 1, age: 1, email: 1 })
      .lean()
    console.timeEnd('lean_select_index')
    process.exit(0)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
})()
```

Comment: An initial guess is that the free M0 sandbox instances run on heavily loaded and shared VMs which results in poor performance.  What do you get if you try a paid instance?

Comment: my personal opinion is that the cloud is a sham. it's best to spend some time learning how to provision your own linux servers. either bare-metal or something like kubernetes clusters. also i'd stay away from running docker inside VMs to avoid layers upon layers of virtualization. if cost is a concern, better start off vith VMs from reliable sellers like vultr, linode, upcloud, etc. when your app grows enough that having noisy neighbors affects performance, move to bare-metal servers.

Comment: @josh3736 - See my edits.

Comment: As far as I can see, the configuration that you use locally is different than the one on the cloud. For example, your cloud instance uses 3 replicas. But you don't have any replicas when you run it locally. Also, there is no information about the hardware that you use. Locally, you may have a six-core i7 processor, 16GB RAM, and a fast SSD. On the cloud, you may have a low CPU, shared RAM and slow SSD (HDD).

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you're dealing with slow network throughput between your local machine and Atlas (something I've experienced myself this week - hence how I found this post!)

Looking at your local query performance:

default_query: 277.986ms

query_with_index: 262.886ms

The query with index isn't noticeably any faster than the one without. For an indexed query to take 262ms in a Node app with a local DB probably means that either:

1. The index isn't being used properly OR more likely...
2. You're returning quite a few results in the query. If the query returns say 3,000 results and each result is 1KB, that's 3MB of JSON data that your app needs to handle.

I've got a 150Mbit/s internet connection and yet my throughput to Atlas (M2 shared tier, if that makes a difference) fluctuates between around 1Mbit/s to 6Mbit/s.

On localhost I have a Mongo query that returns 2,400 results for a total of 1.7MB of JSON data. The roundtrip time for that query in my Node app (using console.time() like you did) connected to Mongo on the same local dev machine is ~150ms. But when connecting that local app to Atlas the query takes 2,400ms to 3,400ms to return. When I profiled the query on Atlas it only took 2ms to execute, so the query itself is really fast, it's apparently the data transfer that's slow.

Based on these results, I have a feeling that Atlas perhaps throttles throughput over the public internet (or just doesn't bother optimizing for it in their network) because 99% of apps are colocated in the same network region as their Atlas DB. That's the reason why they ask you to pick not just AWS, Azure, etc but your specific network region when creating a cluster.

**UPDATE**: I just ran a few Amazon EC2 speed tests for my network region (us-east-1) using a [3rd-party service](http://cloudharmony.com/speedtest-for-aws:ec2-us-east-1) and the average download speed was 4.5Mbit/s for smaller files (1KB to 128KB) and 41Mbit/s for larger files (256KB to 10MB). So the primary issue may be generally slow throughput on the EC2 instances that Atlas clusters run on rather than any throttling by Atlas, or perhaps a combination of both.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, It takes a little bit of time for a request to propagate over the network. this depends on the connection speed, latency, and distance to the server and so many factors. but the server on your local computer doesn't face above mentioned issues as it is for a cloud environment.

But since you are confident about the max delay due to network propagations is ~200ms.

There may be several other possible reasons also to consider

Usually, sandbox plans are for testing and they have limited resources allocated to them. 
They don't use SSD drives to store data and uses cheap storage solutions.
They assume that sandbox plans are usually just for exploring features.
Most of the times those instances are run on shared virtual machines.

Make sure there are no other services running on your computer which consumes a higher data rate eg :( torrent applications )

Answer (score 0):

Cloud services depend on a variety of metrics like System Availability, Response Time, Throughput, Latency and many more...

If the average response time of the user base and the data centers is located in the same region then the average overall response time is about 50ms but if located in the different region the response time significantly increases from 200ms - 400ms which can also depend upon the type of instance you're using and the region which you choose.

Since you're using the Atlas Sandbox cluster you must first select the nearest region to avoid poor performance issues as Atlas Sandbox clusters do have it's own [limitations](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/free-shared-limitations/). If you're looking for quick response time and faster performance try to upgrade your instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that it's not about network issues like latency and bandwidth vs response size, then it's either low edge host (non-SSD, low RAMs) or misconfigured web server/proxy, or there is throttling/filtering happening to your traffic.
To narrow it down more use encrypted (https) connection (it's easy, just install **letsencrypt** on your server) and try to use VPN to change your network route.
Also you can try running the script directly on the server to measure actual executing performance.

Comment: The idea of using a VPN to test how it runs against my own localhost DB is an interesting idea - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you have to consider that your network delay is for each request to the cloud instance , so if you have a ping time of +30ms , you will take 30ms more for each query (approximately) , moreover if your instance is a sandbox ( free account https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/tutorial/deploy-free-tier-cluster/ ) you will have a poor and shared CPU/RAM.

This is why your mongo db queries are slow.

Answer (score 0):

Making a system faster in production is one of the design goals

We need to take into the account many variables:

- Networking, for example, VPC/subnetting
- MongoDB Storage (SSD)
- MongoDB Indexes
- MongoDB RAM, CPU
- Node Web Servers or Cluster
- Cluud Tenants
- TLS encryption

You may need to discard each and every single possible bottleneck